# Framework (Appirater or Armchair) not localized with swift2

Tags: ios, swift, localization, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

So I just started a new swift2 project. To remind the user to rate the app I added Armchair to my Podfile with

```
pod 'Armchair', '~> 0.1.1'
```

No problem there so far, it can be used fine.
Apart from English I also added 6 other languages in the project's Localization section. -> The app gets localized just fine when the device or simulator is set to one of the listed languages.

However the Armchair alert does not get localized.

I also tried with other pod dependencies (like objc Appirater) to verify, but it's the same there.

I also use Appirater in an older objc iOS project and it get's localized just fine.

So is this a strange swift2 - pod dependency - framework issue?
Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks!
Max